# How to display info on the default screen of a Google Nest hub

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to display infos from a Google Sheet to the "lockscreen" (don't know how to call it) of a Google Nest Hub.

I want the info to be displayed all the time and take advantage of this screen that is always on.

Basically that would be a Todo list. I don't understand why I need to invoke an app or talk to my device while the screen is always on with weather, time displayed and the background picture.

WHAT I TRIED SO FAR:

I have serched the generic documentation for Google Assistant (https://developers.google.com/assistant)

I don't see any doc about that or any app available (yet?) that has this feature.

Thanks for any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The platform does not provide a way for third-party apps to add content to the homescreen.